# Sturm's theorem for the number of real roots

Tags: polynomials, roots

If we have Sturm's sequence of polynomials, $p_0=p, p_1, ..., p_m$, for a given polynomial $p$, the number of real roots of $p$ in some half-closed interval $(a,b]$ is $W(a)-W(b)$, where $W$ is function that takes real number $x$ and gives us the number of sign changes in Sturm's sequence, evaluated at $x$.

In order to prove the theorem, we watch what happens to $W$ as $x$ moves from left to right on $x-$axis.
We pick some interval $(a-\epsilon, a+ \epsilon)$ where none of the polynomials in Sturm's sequence is zero, except maybe at $a$.
 We separate the cases when $a$ is zero of some $p_i, i>0$ and when $p_0(a)=0$.

In the first case, we prove that there is the same number of sign changes in triple $(p_{i-1}, p_i, p_{i+1})$ as $x$ moves across $a$.
What I don't understand is how this proves that the number of sign changes stays the same not just when we count it for triple $(p_{i-1}, p_i, p_{i+1})$, but for the whole sequence. What if there is some $p_j, i \neq j$, that is zero at $a$ ? We can apply the proven for triple surrounding $p_j$, but it's not obvious to me that if there is no change of $W$, evaluated at polynomials in groups of three, then there is no change of $W$ evaluated at every polynomial in the sequence.

Also, in the second case, we prove that the number of sign changes drops by $1$ when we cross the zero of $p_0$, but we only prove it for pair $(p_0, p_1)$. How to move from here to counting the number of sign changes in the whole sequence ?

I've searched online and all the proofs are same. They skip the part that I'm talking about (or maybe it's obvious and I don't see it).

Comment: Such a $j$ just means there is another triple $p_{j-1},p_j,p_{j+1}$ that also makes no net change to the number of sign variations. $p_0,p_1$ is examined separately because there is no $p_{-1}$ to form a triple at zeros of $p_0$. This is why it is the only polynomial in the sequence whose zeros actually make changes in $W(x)$. (Note this argument works when $p$ is square-free, because then $i$ and $j$ cannot be adjacent. The argument for non-square-free $p$ has additional complications.)

Comment: @Paul Yes, but you can construct a sequence of polynomials for which there is no change in the number of sign variations in any triple, but the number of sign variations for the whole sequence doesn't stay the same. My question is how to prove that this can't happen with Sturm's sequence, because it's not obvious.

Comment: That doesn't happen in the Sturm sequence either. The number of sign variations changes when $p_0 = 0$ (because $p_0$ is not the center of a triple). This is why the Sturm sequence is useful. If you can create a sequence where triples have 0 total changes, adjacent polynomials are not simultaneously $0$, but has changes in sign variations where the end polynomials are not $0$, I'd love to see it.

Comment: @PaulSinclair  I'm not saying that the theorem is false, I'm just saying that the proof is not complete. You can't say, and I hope you're not saying, that the theorem is true because I can't disprove it. But I want to know whether you see that it's not complete. Do you agree that it's not so obvious how to move from "not changing in groups of three" to "not changing in the whole sequence" ? "That doesn't happen in the Sturm sequence either" - I know that, but what I'm looking for is the proof of this claim, that's what the whole question I posted is about ..

Comment: I'm telling to try backing up your claim that there exist polynomial sequences satisfying the triples condition that none-the-less have sign-variation counts that change at places other than the zeros of the end polynomials. If you attempt this, you will find it impossible, and why it is impossible should help you see what it is that you are missing. A general principle of proving is: If you cannot see how to prove something, try disproving it by working on where you had trouble proving it. If that runs into trouble, see if that trouble helps you get past your original problems in proving.

Comment: I'm sorry that my wording was confusing. By "this doesn't happen for the Sturm sequence either". I meant to contradict your claim "My question is how to prove that this can't happen with Sturm's sequence". I was pointing out that it *does* happen with the Sturm sequence - the number of sign variations for the entire sequence does change, but only at zeros of $p_0$. I don't have time now, but I'm provide a detailed proof for square-free $p_0$ later.

Comment: @PaulSinclair My claim is true, because it wasn't for Sturm's sequences only. Also, I couldn't figure out why can't this happen for Sturm's sequences of polynomials, which is why I posted this question.
By the way, I'm sorry if any of my comments looked offensive. That wasn't my intention.

Comment: No your claim is false. When I asked you to try proving your claim, you will see I very carefully worded it to apply to any sequence (not just the Sturm sequence) meeting the conditions that the Sturm sequence for square-free polynomials meets.

Comment: If the sequence S of polynomials meets the conditions for Sturm's sequence of polynomials, doesn't that make S Sturm's sequence ?
"I was pointing out that it does happen with the Sturm sequence - the number of sign variations for the entire sequence does change, but only at zeros of $p_0$" - I was talking about the case when $p_0$ wasn't zero. I think you can see that from the text from my question.

Comment: The conditions I gave are just some sufficient conditions to show that the sum of sign variations does not change except at zeros of the end polynomials. It happens that the Sturm sequence for a square-free polynomial meets these conditions, but these conditions (triples do not change, adjacent polynomials do not have common zeros) are far more general than the Sturm sequence.

Comment: Got it! I'm looking forward to your answer for the non-square $p$. Thank you for the bunch of replies by the way ..

Answer (score 1):

Let $\sigma(u,v) = 1$ if $u < 0 < v$ or $v < 0 < u$, and $\sigma(u,v) = 0$ otherwise, then for a sequence $\{y_i\}_{i=0}^N$ of *non-zero* values, $$\sum_{i=1}^N \sigma(y_{i-1}, y_i)$$ gives the number of sign variations in the sequence $\{y_i\}$. Unfortunately, it doesn't work when some of the $y_i$ are zero, but I'll work around that.

In particular, if $P = \{p_i\}_{i=0}^N$ is any sequence of non-zero polynomials, then $$W_P(x) = \sum_{i=1}^N \sigma(p_{i-1}(x), p_i(x))$$ except where one or more $p_i(x) = 0$. But that is only at a finite number of isolated points. If on some interval, $p_{i-1}, p_i$ are never $0$, then neither changes sign, so $\sigma(p_{i-1}, p_i)$ is constant on the interval. If $p_i(c) = 0$ for some $c$, there is an open interval about $c$ such that $p_{i-1}, p_i, p_{i+1}$ are not zero everywhere other than at $c$. So to the left of $c$, and to the right of $c$ the number of sign variations in this triple is $$T_i(x) := \sigma(p_{i-1}(x), p_i(x)) + \sigma(p_i(x), p_{i+1}(x))$$
At $c$ itself, the number of sign variations will be $$T_i(c) := \sigma(p_{i-1}(c), p_{i_1}(c))$$
since $p_i(c) = 0$. The basic result is

**Lemma**: if $P = \{p_i\}_{i=0}^N$ is a sequence of non-zero polynomials satisfying the conditions

- for all $i>0$ and $x$, if $p_{i-1}(x) = 0$, then $p_i(x) \ne 0$. I.e., no two adjacent polynomials share a zero.
- for all $i, 0< i < N$ and for all $c$, if $p_i(c) = 0$, then $T_i(x)$ is constant on a neighborhood of $c$.

Then $W_P(x)$ is constant on all intervals that do not include a zero of $p_0$ or $p_N$.

Proof: As noted above the $\sigma(p_{i-1}, p_i)$ are all constant on intervals that do not contain zeros of any of the polynomials, so their sum $W_P(x)$ will also be constant on those intervals. The only place where it can change value is at points $c$ where at least one of the polynomials equals $0$. Since there are only a finite number of such roots, they are isolated from each other.

Let $(a,b)$ be an interval not including any zeros of the two end polynomials and only one zero $c$ of the remaining polynomials. Near $c$ we can divide the indices into two sets $A = \{i\mid p_{i-1}(c) = 0\text{ or } p_i(c) = 0\}, B = \{1, \ldots N\} \setminus A$. Then $$W_P(x) = \sum_{i\in A} \sigma(p_{i-1}(x), p_i(x)) + \sum_{i\in B} \sigma(p_{i-1}(x), p_i(x))$$
Since neither polynomial in the sum ober $B$ is $0$ near $c$, every term, and therefore the sum, is constant. Since no polynomials that are $0$ at $c$ are adjacent, we can rewrite the sum over $A$ as
$$\sum_{i\in A} \sigma(p_{i-1}(x), p_i(x)) = \sum_{p_i(c) = 0} \sigma(p_{i-1}(x), p_i(x)) + \sigma(p_i(x), p_{i+1}(x)) = \sum_{p_i(c) = 0} T_i(x)$$
But by the hypothesis, $T_i(x)$ is constant near $c$ for each $i$ with $p_i(c) = 0$. So the sum over $A$, and therefore $W_P$, are both constant near $c$. Since $W_P$ is constant between any two zeros of the inner polynomials, and also in neighborhoods of those zeros, it must be constant over the entire interval $(a,b)$. QED

The only reason the argument doesn't work for zeros of $p_0$ and $p_N$ is that there is no polynomial on one side to form one of the triples.

---

Now, given a square-free polynomial $p_0$, the Sturm sequence satisfies the recursion $$p_{i-1} + p_{i+1} = q_ip_i$$ for some polynomials $q_i$. If $p_i(c) = 0$ and either of $p_{i-1}(c)$ or $p_{i+1}(c)$ is also zero, then the third polynomial is zero as well. Thus if the Sturm sequence has two adjacent polynomials that are $0$ at $c$, then every polynomial in the sequence must also be equal to $0$ at $c$. This includes $p_0$ itself and $p_1 = p_0'$. But a square-free polynomial and its derivative cannot share a zero. So this cannot occur. Therefore no two adjacent polynomials in the Sturm sequence share a common zero.

Now if $p_i(c) = 0$, we must have $p_{i+1}(c) \ne 0, p_{i-1}(c) \ne 0$, but $p_{i-1}(c) + p_{i+1}(c) = q_i(c)p_i(c) = 0$. Therefore $p_{i+1}(c) = -p_{i-1}(c) \ne 0$, so there must be some neighborhood of $c$ in which $p_{i+1}$ and $p_{i-1}$ are of opposite signs. In this neighborhood except at $c$ itself, $p_i$ must agree in sign with one or the other. Thus there is exactly $1$ sign variation between the three polynomials anywhere in the neighborhood. I.e. $T_i$ is constant on the neighborhood.

So Sturm sequences satisfy both conditions of the lemma, and $W_P$ is constant between zeros of $p_0$ and $p_N$. The final piece of the puzzle is this: For a square-free Sturm sequence, $p_N$ is never $0$. Since $p_N$ is the last polynomial in the sequence, the next remainder must be $0$. But that meant $p_{N-1} = q_Np_N$. So if $p_N(c) = 0$, then so also $p_{N-1}(c) = q_N(c)p_N(c) = 0$. And as indicated above, this means that all polynomials in the sequence are $0$ at $c$, contradicting that $p_0$ is square-free.

Since $p_N$ has no zeros, $W_P$ can only change values at the zeros of $p_0$.

---

The argument breaks down when $p_0$ is not square-free. I have not worked out how the proof must change in this case. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm's_theorem) indicates that the result in the non-square-free case is only a little more restrictive.

Answer (score 0):

Sturm's sequence $(p_0,p_1,\dots,p_m)$ for a polynomial $p$. (Actually, $p$ is not $p_0$ in general, but it does not matter here.).

**Fact 1.** If $p_0(a)=0$, then the number of sign variation of the first pair $(p_0,p_1)$ drops by 1 when $x$ increases from  $x\in (a-\epsilon,a)$ to $x=a$ , and does not change when $x$ increases from $x=a$ to $x\in (a,a+\epsilon)$.

Note that Fact 1 is stronger than the OP claimed in the question statement, which will explain why the type of the interval is $(a,b]$.

**Fact 2.** If $p_{i}(a)=0$ for $1\leq j\leq m-1$, then $p_{i-1}(a)p_{i+1}(a)<0$, which implies the number of sign variations in the triple $(p_{j-1},p_j,p_{j+1})$ does not change.

**Fact 3.** By definition of $p_m$, it is a nonzero constant and never changes sign.

**Case 1.** $p_0(a)=0$.

Step 1. According to Fact 1, as $x$ moves from left to right across $x$, the number of sign variations for the first pair $(p_0,p_1)$ drops by 1. **The contribution of $(p_0,p_1)$ to the change in $W$ is $-1$.**

Step 2. Consider any $i$ such that $p_i(a)=0, 1\leq i\leq m-1$. According to Fact 2, one can prove that the number of sign variations for the triple $(p_{i-1},p_i,p_{i+1})$ does not change. **The contribution of $(p_{i-1},p_i,p_{i+1})$ to the change in $W$ is $0$.**

Step 3. Only those pairs $(p_i,p_{i+1})$ for which both $p_i(a)$ and $p_{i+1}(a)$ are nonzero remain to be checked. This is because:

i. If $p_i(a)=0$, then we have already considered the contribution of  $(p_i,p_{i+1})$ to the change in $W$ in the triple $(p_{i-1}, p_i, p_{i+1})$ for $1 \leq i\leq m-1$, or it's just the pair $(p_0,p_1)$ for $i=0$.

ii. If $p_{i+1}(a)=0$, then we have already considered the contribution of $(p_i,p_{i+1})$ to the change in $W$ in the triple $(p_i,p_{i+1},p_{i+2})$ for $1\leq i\leq m-2$.

And we don't need to worry about $p_{i-1}$ and $p_{i+2}$, because no matter if they are zero, the involved pairs are $(p_{i-1},p_i)$ (maybe in the triple $(p_{i-2},p_{i-1},p_i)$) and $(p_{i+1},p_{i+2})$ (maybe in the triple $(p_{i+1},p_{i+2},p_{i+3})$), respectively, not the pair $(p_i,p_{i+1})$ we are now considering.

But since $p_i(a)$ and $p_{i+1}(a)$ are both nonzero, they don't change sign as $x$ moves from $x\in (a-\epsilon,a)$ to $x\in (a,a+\epsilon)$. Therefore the number of sign variations for the pair $(p_i,p_{i+1})$ doesn't change and **its contribution to the change in $W$ is $0$.**

Step 1~3 cover all possible changes in sign variations, either due to pairs in a triple or as individual pairs. The total change in $W$ is $-1+0+0=-1$, and $W$ drops by 1 as $x$ increases from $x\in (a-\epsilon,a)$ to $x\in (a,a+\epsilon)$.

**Case 2. $p_0(a)\neq 0$.**

The only difference from case 1 is Step 1, where the contribution of the pair $(p_0,p_1)$ to the change in $W$ becomes $0$. It follows that in this case $W$ does not change as $x$ increases from $x\in (a-\epsilon,a)$ to $x\in (a,a+\epsilon)$.